# Python - import error of opengm

Tags: python

I installed OpenGM library with Python wrapper. The wrapper is installed to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opengm.

However I can only import opengm when I'm in the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opengm folder. When I cd to other places, I get import error module not found.

That happens only for opengm. All other packages in the site-packages path can be imported successfully. How do I fix the problem?

Comment: Show us, don't tell us.  Show us the commands you typed, your PYTHONPATH, the value of sys.path, and the exact error output.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow site-packages are not included in sys.path, only dist-packages. I moved the package to dist-packages and it works!